# Oracle Hierarchical Query - extended info required

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

I have the below data which represents a employee hierarchy, and I need to identify all of the possible permutations of employee/supervisor.
I have had a look at the oracle Tree Walk which seems like it should do the job, but I cannot quite get it working. The issue is I need to list a row for each combination of manager/employee, this includes the managers manager etc.
(I have edited to add in Names to query)

Does anyone have an ideas how this could be done?

**DATA**

```
SUPER SUP_NAME        EMP    EMP_NAME
^^^^^ ^^^^^^^          ^^^   ^^^^^^^
1     Big Boss         100   Sub Boss
100   Sub Boss         200   Field Boss
200   Field Boss       300   Field Emp
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
SUPER    EMP  SUP_NAME      EMP_NAME
^^^^^    ^^^  ^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^
1        100   Big Boss     Sub Boss
1        200   Big Boss     Field Boss
1        300   Big Boss     Field Emp
100      200   Sub Boss     Field Boss
100      300   Sub Boss     Field Emp
200      300   Field Boss   Field Emp
300            Field Emp
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far techGuy..?

Comment: I have tried the one by 'Ponder Stibbons' (union) just a little while ago, and it worked perfectly, though I couldn't figure out the correct way to get the names added into it, so have edited the original question to ask how to pull the names across as well.

Comment: Now updated the answer by @ponderstibbons to include the revised columns of supername, empname which works, see the top answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `connect_by_root` in standard hierarchical query and add employees who are not managers using `union` and `minus`:

```
select connect_by_root(super) super, emp from data connect by super = prior emp
union
select emp, null from data minus select super, null from data
```

---

Test:

```
with data (super, emp) as (
    select   1, 100 from dual union all
    select 100, 200 from dual union all
    select 200, 300 from dual )
select connect_by_root(super) super, emp from data connect by super = prior emp
union
select emp, null from data minus select super, null from data
```

Result:

```
     SUPER        EMP
---------- ----------
         1        100
         1        200
         1        300
       100        200
       100        300
       200        300
       300 
7 rows selected
```

Comment: Good answer! Two suggestions though: (1) Use UNION ALL - there is no reason for the far less efficient UNION; (2) use a NOT IN clause (an anti-join), instead of the far less efficient MINUS operation.

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, I used the 'Union' one, so thank you for your assistance. I was trying to add the Supervisor name & Emp name, but I cannot seem to get it working correctly, how can I add them into the Union query?

Comment: @ponderstibbons - Updated you answer to add in the other columns I have added to the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Note that you will need a row with `300, NULL` to include `300, NULL`  in the result set.

```
    WITH yourtable (super, emp )
     AS (SELECT 1,
                100
         FROM   dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 100,
                200
         FROM   dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 200,
                300
         FROM   dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 300,
                NULL
         FROM   dual),
     datatable
     AS (SELECT super,
                Ltrim(Sys_connect_by_path(emp, ','), ',') path
         FROM   yourtable
         START WITH emp IS NULL
         CONNECT BY PRIOR super = emp)
SELECT DISTINCT super,
                Regexp_substr(path, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
FROM   datatable
CONNECT BY Regexp_substr(path, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY super;
```

Comment: Perhaps this will work, but it is highly inefficient. Use standard hierarchical query features instead, as @ponderstibbons has shown.

Comment: @mathguy : Yes. didn't realize about `connect_by_root(super)`